# Hard disk one partition as file system

Tags: partitioning

[image]

This is the first time to use my laptop Dell inspiron and it's coming with Ubuntu  even I can't know the version.

But the main issue as you can see in photo.
My hard disk is 1 TB and the main bulk 980 GB is the file system .
So how can I make a new partition to be for my files? I can't of course make a new folder in the system partition.

Comment: You need to use live installer, so all partitions unmounted and shrink sda3, then you can create additional partition (s). If you want it as /home you can do this: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 although perhaps easier to reinstall. See this for any partition on any drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: Why "can't you make a new folder"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can create any folder you like in your home folder to put your files in. The home folder is part of the filesystem. It is absolutely not nessecary to create a separate partition for your files or put your home directory on a different partition. To access your home folder just open the filebrowser, in your case based on the screenshot above, this would be the icon looking like a filecabinet, the second from above on the left of your screen. It is  called files if you hover with your mousepointer above it.

It is common to install Ubuntu like it is installed on your laptop, certainly not an issue.